# Enabling Agentless Discovery for Kubernetes Extension in Defender for Cloud: Achieving Policy-Based Implementation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-policy

I am currently working on developing a custom azure policy that facilitates agentless discovery for the Kubernetes extension in Defender for Cloud. While I came across a script that utilizes the API to enable the extension, my objective is to accomplish this through a Azure policy instead.

This is the script:

source: https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft-Defender-for-Cloud/blob/main/Powershell%20scripts/Agentless%20Container%20Posture/Onboarding.ps1

```html
    <# NOT MY CODE
    .SYNOPSIS
        Enable Defender for Cloud cloud posture plan with containers related features.
    .DESCRIPTION
        A longer description.
    .PARAMETER SubscriptionsListFile
        Path to file containing subscriptions list.
        Subscriptions expected to be separated by new line
    .EXAMPLE
        onboard.ps1 subscriptions.txt
    #>

param(
    $SubscriptionsListFile
)

function main()
{
    az login --use-device-code

    $regex = ''
    foreach($line in Get-Content -Path $SubscriptionsListFile) 
    {
        if($line -match $regex)
        {
            handleSubscription $line
        }
    }
}

function handleSubscription($subscription)
{
    echo "Handling subscription $subscription"
    
    # Account set
    az account set -s $line
    
    # Call Pricing API
    $auth = az account get-access-token --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
    $token = "$($auth.tokenType) $($auth.accessToken)"
    enableMdcPricing $subscription $token
    
    echo "Done for subscription $subscription"
}

function enableMdcPricing($subscription, $token)
{
    $url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscription/providers/Microsoft.Security/pricings/cloudposture/?api-version=2023-01-01"
    
    $body = "{`"properties`":{`"pricingTier`":`"Standard`",`"extensions`":[{`"name`":`"AgentlessDiscoveryForKubernetes`",`"isEnabled`":`"True`"},{`"name`":`"ContainerRegistriesVulnerabilityAssessments`",`"isEnabled`":`"True`"}]}}"

    $headers = @{
        "Accept" = "application/json"
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
        "Authorization" = $token
    }
    
    # Invoke
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method 'PUT' -Body $body -Headers $headers
}

main
```

Although I have put in my best effort to comprehend the process, I must admit that policy creation is not my strongest suit. Nonetheless, I am attempting to enable the extension. Upon deploying, I have noticed that the policy is compliant; however, the agentless discovery for the Kubernetes extension remains "off" in the Defender for Cloud settings for each subscription.

My objective is to deploy the extension to a management group so that all subscriptions underneath it inherit the enabled state.

```html
{
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "DeployIfNotExists",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
    }
  },
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "name": "cloudposture",
        "deploymentScope": "subscription",
        "existenceScope": "subscription",
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
        ],
        "existenceCondition": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Security/pricings/pricingTier",
              "equals": "Standard"
            }
          ]
        },
        "deployment": {
          "location": "westeurope",
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "parameters": {},
            "template": {
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {},
              "variables": {},
              "resources": [
                {
                  "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
                  "apiVersion": "2023-01-01",
                  "name": "cloudposture",
                  "properties": {
                    "pricingTier": "Standard",
                    "extensions": [
                      {
                        "name": "AgentlessDiscoveryForKubernetes",
                        "isEnabled": "True"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "outputs": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

thank you